# How to run Blockly from the cloned repository?

Tags: git, github, blockly

I am trying run Google's Blockly.

https://github.com/google/blockly

I am learning how to use git bash for windows, and I have linked git with my Github account.  I cloned the repository of blockly and I am able to view all of the files on my computer.

My question is:

How do I know which file will run blockly?  This may seem dumb, but there is a mess of files, and I see no .exe file.  This is frustrating me because I have all the files on my computer, but I still can't run the dang application.

Comment: You should look for `index.html`, that is a web-based project.

Answer (score 2):

It is a JavaScript library that you include in a website. You can run it locally but you will need to create a webpage and include the correct scripts.

Their getting started guide is quite good. Please
reference here: https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/get-started/web

More specifically, how to inject blockly into your web site: 
https://developers.google.com/blockly/guides/configure/web/fixed-size

@zatta is correct. There are a bunch of demos in the project located here:
https://github.com/google/blockly/tree/master/demos

Each contains an index.html file that can be opened with your browser.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.

Comment: Great if you are having issues let us know. If it works please accept as answer.